# JAVA - How do I keep data stored into a internal DB (running SQL if possible)

Tags: java, sql, database, internal

My problem is that I don't even know what I am looking for ... 
I created an app that should save data even without an internet connection and than update it into a External Server running SQL.I need to have my application to store the data into the pc itself

How do I accomplih that? What am I looking for? Derby?

Comment: Thanks. I´ll look into it. I'll let you know how it workrd.

Answer (score 1):

in your code use
`static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/dataBasename`"

Comment: I'm guessing that's Derby.  I'll see how that works. Thanks for repleying

Comment: That's actually MySQL, which isn't what you want (unless you want everyone that installs your program to also install MySQL). What m4rtin said, Derby or H2 - I have a program that transparently switches from them to PostgreSQL.

Comment: i just give him a code exemple he can change the jdbc driver as he like